# oracle: Column datatype in 'char' getting converted to date format while extracting to excel

Tags: excel, oracle, toad

A column has values like `'05-11'` in char datatype. But when I export the records into excel file, it gets converted to `05-Nov`. How to fix this issue in PL/SQL?

I tried the below code.code is the column name

```
Update query_table q set code = 
substr(q.code,0,instr(q.code,'-')-1)||'-'||substr(q.code,instr(q.code,'-')+1,2);
```

But this doesn't seem to be working. Please help if you have faced similar issue before?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem with data, this is Excel trying to be helpful. It's seeing a value of `05-11` and - thinking it recognises some form of date - renders it with the standard date format.

Possibly you can fixing Excel display defaults. But the safest approach would be to change the export so it wraps the column in double-quotes. Excel on seeing `"05-11"` will recognise it as a string and not mess with it. You can make this happen by configuring the export tool. For instance, if you're using the TOAD Export Wizard there should be an option (maybe a checkbox?) to apply double-quotes to exported values.

Comment: Hi..I have also one column in date datatype in this table. How can the excel differentiate column in char and column in date? is there anything I can do in the pl/sql coding part? I did extraction from the front end of application.

Comment: If you want me to comment on your code you'll need to post a (redacted) example of it, and some sample data which illustrates the problem you're experiencing

Answer (score 0):

aiswarya, try placing the value in double quotes "05-11" when you generate it.